# Relative import from a package

Tags: python, python-import

Works fine like this

```
serj@venus ~/work/hello $ tree -L 3 .
.
├── hello
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── package
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── module.py
└── main.py

serj@venus ~/work/hello $ cat main.py
from hello.package.module import print_hello

print_hello()

serj@venus ~/work/hello $ python main.py
Hello Void
```

But when I move main.py into hello package and change import string to start with .

```
serj@venus ~/work/hello/hello $ tree -L 3 ..
..
├── hello
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── main.py
│   └── package
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── module.py
│       └── module.pyc
└── README

serj@venus ~/work/hello/hello $ cat main.py
from .package.module import print_hello

print_hello()

serj@venus ~/work/hello/hello $ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .package.module import print_hello
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

why it reports hello as non-package? details details details

Comment: Have you tried to remove the first point in the import `from package.module import print_hello`

Comment: If you want to run a module as part of a package, you need to use `python -m hello.main`.  Running `python main.py` will import the named file as `__main__` module, which is never part of a package.